# Changing library path with hook_library_info_alter

Tags: 8, hooks

I am having difficulties to change the library path defined by another module in *.libraries.yml via hook_library_info_alter

Essentially I have one module defining a library component in its *.libraries.yml like that:

```
# Font Awesome
fontawesome:
  version: 4.7.0
  css:
    component:
      /libraries/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: {minified: true }
```

How has my hook to look like to change to path to:

> /libraries/fontawesome/**web-fonts-with-css**/font-awesome.min.css

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed my patch for social icons module to add dynamic font awesome css here
https://www.drupal.org/project/social_icons/issues/2984954

This is helpful to you.

```
if (isset($libraries['font-awesome'])) {
     $library_key = key($libraries['font-awesome']['css']['theme']);
     $library_array = $libraries['font-awesome']['css']['theme'][$library_key];
     unset($libraries['font-awesome']['css']['theme'][$library_key]);
     $libraries['font-awesome']['css']['theme'][$font_awesome_url] = $library_array;
}
```